# What is the best way to load new javascript file after jQuery post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready, jquery-post

In my app I use Ajax navigation with jQuery post.

**Scenario:**

Lets suppose a user types the url and loads the index page. Now he wants to go to his profile page(suppose he is already logged in previously). Clicking at "My profile" link, a jQuery post is executed and it returns the html result in the main div.

**The problem i have:**

The profile page, has its own profile_functions.js file which contains the profile related js functions.At the jQuery post, i do checks, so when the user profile page is requested then it loads the profile_functions.js before doing the jQuery post. (appends it using `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(file);`)

Inside the profile_functions.js i have some jQuery plugins which need to initialize using `$(document).ready(function(){   });` which is placed at the HTML result. The problem i have noticed is that sometimes the jQuery post result is retrieved earlier than the load of the .js file has been completed, so i get an error and of course the jQuery plugin doesn't work.

So my question is: Using jQuery post, what is the best and successful way to load the new .js file which is required from the post result-html code?

**EDIT:** As requested, here is the code I have:

```
//Loads the new JS
function loadjscss(filename, filetype){
        if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
            var fileref=document.createElement('script');
            fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
            fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
        }else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
            var fileref=document.createElement("link");
            fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
            fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
            fileref.setAttribute("href", filename);
        }
        if (typeof fileref!="undefined"){document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);}
    }

//Part of function that loads the new page
function ajax_menu_nav(requested_page) {
    if(requested_page=='profile_page'){
        loadjscss("/static/profile_functions.js", "js");
    }   
    $.post("/ajax_menu.php",
        {
            rp:requested_page,
            rand:Math.random() 
        } ,
        function(rd) {
            $('#main').html(rd.tpl);
        }, "json"
    );
}
```

Now the result HTML code contains among the others:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ function_a(); });
```

Which the function_a() is from profile_functions.js file.

Comment: "The problem i have noticed is that sometimes the jQuery post result is retrieved earlier than the load of the .js file has been completed" Can you post the code that does this please? Hard to resolve without it.

Comment: Why don't you trigger the AJAX function in the [onload callback](http://mdn.io/script%20onload) of the script element? Or start using [promises](http://mdn.io/promise)? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that function_a is called when DOM is ready and therefore before script is loaded. You should call it by yourself when script is loaded, in a callback.

Answer (score 0):

Including the javascript with the html file might be the only way to be sure everything loads nicely.  The way you have it set up, you can't be sure which will load first, the js file, or what ajax_menu.php returns.

I've fiddle with loading whole page content this way, and it can be a pain, and messy looking (javascript all over the place for each page load).  You can also run into more problems down the road.  That's just from experience though, if you can do it, do it.

EDIT:  One thing you can try is, put the $.post() request in the js file you are including.  Then all you have to do is add the js file, and it does the rest (it loads it's own page)